# Chrome extension delete specific history events

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-history

I'm creating a chrome extension with some useful tools, including a history overview. I found out that i can read my chrome history using

```
chrome.history.search({
    text: MySearchString, 
    maxResults: 100
}, function(data) {
    ... loop my results ...
});
```

Using the history search, i created a list with checkboxes. I want to delete specific events in my chrome history. I found out i can delete specific urls by using

```
chrome.history.deleteUrl({ 'url': myUrl });
```

but it seems this only removes the selected url from the chrome.history and doesn't affect the history found on chrome://history/

Can anyone tell me how to delete specific events?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's https://crbug.com/395955 - chrome.history.deleteUrl does not affect synced history. Will be fixed in Chrome 74.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, I guess this is one of the few times the bug is fixed by itself if i wait long enough ;-)